# How to trigger two onClick events in one button?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to open from the index.php receipt.php and hide the button as receipt is already made, ie. two events in one submit button. This hides the button but the submit doesn't trigger.

```
<action =receipt.php target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="Receipt"     onClick="hideme();this.form.submit()" id="abc"> ... *rest of the form inputs* </form>

<script>
function hideme() {
    ,document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: The act of submitting the form to `receipt.php` will load a new page so any changes made( ie hiding the button ) on the original page will be ephemeral/temporary. Incidentally you omitted the `form` from the opening html tag

Comment: The button `abc` does not have any `innerHTML` - it has a `value`

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `hideme` function to submit the form in addition to hiding/modifying the `submit` button you could try like this:

Add an `event` argument to the inline `onclick` function call - that allows the function to access all the properties of the [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and the important one here is the `target`

This should disabled the button and modify the `value` AND submit the form to a new window with a single `event`..

You could uncomment the line that removes the button as alternative or simply set the button's value as empty.

```js
function hideme(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.parentNode.submit();
  //e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);//to remove the button completely or...
  e.target.value='Submitted';
  e.target.disabled=true;
}
```

```html
<form action='receipt.php' target='_blank'>

    <input type="submit" value="Receipt" onclick="hideme(event);" />

    <!-- 
        *rest of the form inputs*
    -->
</form>
```